# SQL Server update query triggered by stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-trigger

Is there a way to have a SQL Server stored procedure trigger a query without editing the stored procedure code?

I am looking for a way to do something along the lines of a `CREATE TRIGGER`, but have it be triggered by a stored procedure instead of table update without altering the original code for the stored procedure.

I would create a trigger for when the table updates, but the stored procedure that updates the table updates it tens of thousands of times, so that is unfeasible.

Comment: Triggers can only placed on tables and views; you can't place one of an SP. If the logic of the SP needs to change, you need to update the SP.

Comment: Along the same lines of Randall Porter's answer...you could create a new procedure to do what you want, and then put both the existing procedure and the new one into a single job.  This will work if you are calling the existing procedure on a schedule.  If you are calling it programatically, change either the application code to also call the second procedure, or change the existing procedure code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
```

I would check the "execution_count" to the system table listed above. You can create a stored procedure and then create a job that runs that stored procedure at a specified interval.